# How to get the element from promise in react?

Tags: reactjs, promise, console, console.log, openfin

From these 2 lines I am getting a promise in my console but not getting how I can access the values from it.

```
const name = fin.Application.getCurrentUser().getName();
console.log(name);
```

The result which I am getting in console is:-

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
```

In [[PromiseResult]]: Object there is a field for name and I want to access it.

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]:Promise
[[PromiseState]]:"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]:Object
      name:{}
```

How it can be done?
I have tried it using then() but not getting the desired result.
Like this:-
const app = fin.Application.getCurrentUser().getName().then((app) => console.log(app));

Comment: "*I have tried it using then() but not getting the desired result.*" - please [edit] your question to show us your attempt

Comment: @Bergi Added the same.

Comment: Yes, `const app` won't (and can never) immediately get the desired result value, but the logging of the `app` argument to the `then` callback should work, no?

Comment: @Bergi Yes I have tried it but it's not working. Can you write a line about how you are saying to approach.

Comment: `fin.Application.getCurrentUser().getName().then((app) => console.log(app));` **will** work. What does it log?

Comment: @Bergi It's not loging the name part which I needed.

Comment: You mean `.then(app => console.log(app.name))`? What was it logging instead? Or did it not log anything?

Comment: @Bergi Its not logging anything

Comment: Then you might be getting an error now. Add `.catch(console.error)`. But you were claiming before that the promise fulfills with a result… If it no longer resolves, you might have a problem in `getName()`.